# Reference to generic type '<YourStruct>' requires arguments in <...>

Tags: swift, properties, protocols, codable

I am trying to model [the TDAmeritrade api](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/account-access/apis/get/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D-0) using the codable protocols.  You can see the example JSON in the "Response Summary" section.   All the values for the `Account` seem to be fine, except for the `positions` property.

The instrument property of the Position struct can be one of 5 types: `Option`, `CashEquivalent`, `MutualFund`, `FixedIncome`, and `Equity`. I figured out that I can make the instrument property of position a Codable Instrument by making a generic type for position.

In the positions property will have 0 or more positions with an Option as its instrument property, 0 or more positions with a CashEquivalent as its instrument property, 0 or more positions with a MutualFund as its instrument property, 0 or more positions with a FixedIncome as its instrument property, and/or 0 or more positions with an Equity as its instrument property.

How can I fix this error and properly represent this JSON I'm given?

```
protocol Instrument: Codable {}

extension Option: Instrument {}
extension CashEquivalent: Instrument {}
extension MutualFund: Instrument {}
extension FixedIncome: Instrument {}
extension Equity: Instrument {}

struct Position<T: Instrument>: Codable {
    let shortQuantity, averagePrice, currentDayProfitLoss, currentDayProfitLossPercentage: Double
    let longQuantity, settledLongQuantity, settledShortQuantity, agedQuantity: Double
    let instrument: T
    let marketValue: Double
}

// MARK: - Account
struct Account: Codable {

    enum AccountType {
        case MARGIN, CASH
    }

    let type: AccountType
    let accountID: String
    let roundTrips: Int
    let isDayTrader, isClosingOnlyRestricted: Bool
    let positions: [Position]
    let orderStrategies: [OrderStrategy]
    let initialBalances: InitialBalances
    let currentBalances: Balances
    let projectedBalances: Balances

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case accountID = "accountId"
        case roundTrips, isDayTrader, isClosingOnlyRestricted, positions, orderStrategies, initialBalances, currentBalances, projectedBalances
    }
}
```

For the readers that like comprehensive code.  Here are the rest of the objects I have. If I am accidentally missing one, for these intents and purposes, you can substitute it with a simple `codable` type like a string: ie: `typeAlias AssetType = String`.

```
struct Option: Codable {
    let assetType: AssetType
    let cusip, symbol, optionDescription: String
    let type: OptionType
    let putCall: PutCall
    let underlyingSymbol: String
    let optionMultiplier: Int
    let optionDeliverables: [OptionDeliverable]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetType, cusip, symbol
        case optionDescription = "description"
        case type, putCall, underlyingSymbol, optionMultiplier, optionDeliverables
    }
}

struct CashEquivalent: Codable {
    let assetType: AssetType
    let cusip, symbol, cashEquivalentDescription: String
    let type: CashEquivalentType

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetType, cusip, symbol
        case cashEquivalentDescription = "description"
        case type
    }
}

struct MutualFund: Codable {
    let assetType: AssetType
    let cusip, symbol, mutualFundDescription: String
    let type: MutualFundType

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetType, cusip, symbol
        case mutualFundDescription = "description"
        case type
    }
}

struct FixedIncome: Codable {
    let assetType: AssetType
    let cusip, symbol, fixedIncomeDescription: String
    let maturityDate: String
    let variableRate, factor: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetType, cusip, symbol
        case fixedIncomeDescription = "description"
        case maturityDate, variableRate, factor
    }
}

struct Equity: InstrumentCodable {
    var assetType: AssetType
    var cusip: String
    var symbol: Symbol
    var description: String
}
```

Here is an example JSON response from my most recent call to the account's api:

```
{
  "securitiesAccount": {
    "type": "CASH",
    "accountId": "111111111",
    "roundTrips": 0,
    "isDayTrader": false,
    "isClosingOnlyRestricted": false,
    "positions": [
      {
        "shortQuantity": 0,
        "averagePrice": 0.58,
        "currentDayProfitLoss": 1.8,
        "currentDayProfitLossPercentage": 0.34,
        "longQuantity": 9,
        "settledLongQuantity": 9,
        "settledShortQuantity": 0,
        "instrument": {
          "assetType": "EQUITY",
          "cusip": "26605Q106",
          "symbol": "DXF"
        },
        "marketValue": 7.02
      },
      {
        "shortQuantity": 0,
        "averagePrice": 0.47,
        "currentDayProfitLoss": -0.03,
        "currentDayProfitLossPercentage": -0.06,
        "longQuantity": 1,
        "settledLongQuantity": 1,
        "settledShortQuantity": 0,
        "instrument": {
          "assetType": "EQUITY",
          "cusip": "79971C201",
          "symbol": "SNMP"
        },
        "marketValue": 0.44
      }
    ],
    "initialBalances": {
      "accruedInterest": 0,
      "cashAvailableForTrading": 94.31,
      "cashAvailableForWithdrawal": 94.31,
      "cashBalance": 94.31,
      "bondValue": 0,
      "cashReceipts": 0,
      "liquidationValue": 100.57,
      "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
      "longStockValue": 6.26,
      "moneyMarketFund": 0,
      "mutualFundValue": 0,
      "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
      "shortStockValue": 0,
      "isInCall": false,
      "unsettledCash": 0,
      "cashDebitCallValue": 0,
      "pendingDeposits": 0,
      "accountValue": 100.57
    },
    "currentBalances": {
      "accruedInterest": 0,
      "cashBalance": 94.31,
      "cashReceipts": 0,
      "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
      "liquidationValue": 101.77,
      "longMarketValue": 7.46,
      "moneyMarketFund": 0,
      "savings": 0,
      "shortMarketValue": 0,
      "pendingDeposits": 0,
      "cashAvailableForTrading": 94.31,
      "cashAvailableForWithdrawal": 94.31,
      "cashCall": 0,
      "longNonMarginableMarketValue": 94.31,
      "totalCash": 94.31,
      "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
      "bondValue": 0,
      "cashDebitCallValue": 0,
      "unsettledCash": 0
    },
    "projectedBalances": {
      "cashAvailableForTrading": 94.31,
      "cashAvailableForWithdrawal": 94.31
    }
  }
}
```

The example JSON provided by the TDAmeritrade API:

```
//Account:
{
  "securitiesAccount": "The type <securitiesAccount> has the following subclasses [MarginAccount, CashAccount] descriptions are listed below"
}

//The class <securitiesAccount> has the 
//following subclasses: 
//-MarginAccount
//-CashAccount
//JSON for each are listed below: 

//MarginAccount:
{
  "type": "'CASH' or 'MARGIN'",
  "accountId": "string",
  "roundTrips": 0,
  "isDayTrader": false,
  "isClosingOnlyRestricted": false,
  "positions": [
    {
      "shortQuantity": 0,
      "averagePrice": 0,
      "currentDayProfitLoss": 0,
      "currentDayProfitLossPercentage": 0,
      "longQuantity": 0,
      "settledLongQuantity": 0,
      "settledShortQuantity": 0,
      "agedQuantity": 0,
      "instrument": "The type <Instrument> has the following subclasses [Equity, FixedIncome, MutualFund, CashEquivalent, Option] descriptions are listed below\"",
      "marketValue": 0
    }
  ],
  "orderStrategies": [
    {
      "session": "'NORMAL' or 'AM' or 'PM' or 'SEAMLESS'",
      "duration": "'DAY' or 'GOOD_TILL_CANCEL' or 'FILL_OR_KILL'",
      "orderType": "'MARKET' or 'LIMIT' or 'STOP' or 'STOP_LIMIT' or 'TRAILING_STOP' or 'MARKET_ON_CLOSE' or 'EXERCISE' or 'TRAILING_STOP_LIMIT' or 'NET_DEBIT' or 'NET_CREDIT' or 'NET_ZERO'",
      "cancelTime": {
        "date": "string",
        "shortFormat": false
      },
      "complexOrderStrategyType": "'NONE' or 'COVERED' or 'VERTICAL' or 'BACK_RATIO' or 'CALENDAR' or 'DIAGONAL' or 'STRADDLE' or 'STRANGLE' or 'COLLAR_SYNTHETIC' or 'BUTTERFLY' or 'CONDOR' or 'IRON_CONDOR' or 'VERTICAL_ROLL' or 'COLLAR_WITH_STOCK' or 'DOUBLE_DIAGONAL' or 'UNBALANCED_BUTTERFLY' or 'UNBALANCED_CONDOR' or 'UNBALANCED_IRON_CONDOR' or 'UNBALANCED_VERTICAL_ROLL' or 'CUSTOM'",
      "quantity": 0,
      "filledQuantity": 0,
      "remainingQuantity": 0,
      "requestedDestination": "'INET' or 'ECN_ARCA' or 'CBOE' or 'AMEX' or 'PHLX' or 'ISE' or 'BOX' or 'NYSE' or 'NASDAQ' or 'BATS' or 'C2' or 'AUTO'",
      "destinationLinkName": "string",
      "releaseTime": "string",
      "stopPrice": 0,
      "stopPriceLinkBasis": "'MANUAL' or 'BASE' or 'TRIGGER' or 'LAST' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'ASK_BID' or 'MARK' or 'AVERAGE'",
      "stopPriceLinkType": "'VALUE' or 'PERCENT' or 'TICK'",
      "stopPriceOffset": 0,
      "stopType": "'STANDARD' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'LAST' or 'MARK'",
      "priceLinkBasis": "'MANUAL' or 'BASE' or 'TRIGGER' or 'LAST' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'ASK_BID' or 'MARK' or 'AVERAGE'",
      "priceLinkType": "'VALUE' or 'PERCENT' or 'TICK'",
      "price": 0,
      "taxLotMethod": "'FIFO' or 'LIFO' or 'HIGH_COST' or 'LOW_COST' or 'AVERAGE_COST' or 'SPECIFIC_LOT'",
      "orderLegCollection": [
        {
          "orderLegType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
          "legId": 0,
          "instrument": "\"The type <Instrument> has the following subclasses [Equity, FixedIncome, MutualFund, CashEquivalent, Option] descriptions are listed below\"",
          "instruction": "'BUY' or 'SELL' or 'BUY_TO_COVER' or 'SELL_SHORT' or 'BUY_TO_OPEN' or 'BUY_TO_CLOSE' or 'SELL_TO_OPEN' or 'SELL_TO_CLOSE' or 'EXCHANGE'",
          "positionEffect": "'OPENING' or 'CLOSING' or 'AUTOMATIC'",
          "quantity": 0,
          "quantityType": "'ALL_SHARES' or 'DOLLARS' or 'SHARES'"
        }
      ],
      "activationPrice": 0,
      "specialInstruction": "'ALL_OR_NONE' or 'DO_NOT_REDUCE' or 'ALL_OR_NONE_DO_NOT_REDUCE'",
      "orderStrategyType": "'SINGLE' or 'OCO' or 'TRIGGER'",
      "orderId": 0,
      "cancelable": false,
      "editable": false,
      "status": "'AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER' or 'AWAITING_CONDITION' or 'AWAITING_MANUAL_REVIEW' or 'ACCEPTED' or 'AWAITING_UR_OUT' or 'PENDING_ACTIVATION' or 'QUEUED' or 'WORKING' or 'REJECTED' or 'PENDING_CANCEL' or 'CANCELED' or 'PENDING_REPLACE' or 'REPLACED' or 'FILLED' or 'EXPIRED'",
      "enteredTime": "string",
      "closeTime": "string",
      "tag": "string",
      "accountId": 0,
      "orderActivityCollection": [
        "\"The type <OrderActivity> has the following subclasses [Execution] descriptions are listed below\""
      ],
      "replacingOrderCollection": [
        {}
      ],
      "childOrderStrategies": [
        {}
      ],
      "statusDescription": "string"
    }
  ],
  "initialBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "availableFundsNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "buyingPower": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashAvailableForTrading": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPower": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPowerCall": 0,
    "dayTradingEquityCall": 0,
    "equity": 0,
    "equityPercentage": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarginValue": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "longStockValue": 0,
    "maintenanceCall": 0,
    "maintenanceRequirement": 0,
    "margin": 0,
    "marginEquity": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "regTCall": 0,
    "shortMarginValue": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "shortStockValue": 0,
    "totalCash": 0,
    "isInCall": false,
    "unsettledCash": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "marginBalance": 0,
    "shortBalance": 0,
    "accountValue": 0
  },
  "currentBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarketValue": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "savings": 0,
    "shortMarketValue": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "availableFunds": 0,
    "availableFundsNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "buyingPower": 0,
    "buyingPowerNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPower": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPowerCall": 0,
    "equity": 0,
    "equityPercentage": 0,
    "longMarginValue": 0,
    "maintenanceCall": 0,
    "maintenanceRequirement": 0,
    "marginBalance": 0,
    "regTCall": 0,
    "shortBalance": 0,
    "shortMarginValue": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "sma": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "isInCall": false,
    "stockBuyingPower": 0,
    "optionBuyingPower": 0
  },
  "projectedBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarketValue": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "savings": 0,
    "shortMarketValue": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "availableFunds": 0,
    "availableFundsNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "buyingPower": 0,
    "buyingPowerNonMarginableTrade": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPower": 0,
    "dayTradingBuyingPowerCall": 0,
    "equity": 0,
    "equityPercentage": 0,
    "longMarginValue": 0,
    "maintenanceCall": 0,
    "maintenanceRequirement": 0,
    "marginBalance": 0,
    "regTCall": 0,
    "shortBalance": 0,
    "shortMarginValue": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "sma": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "isInCall": false,
    "stockBuyingPower": 0,
    "optionBuyingPower": 0
  }
}

//OR

//CashAccount:
{
  "type": "'CASH' or 'MARGIN'",
  "accountId": "string",
  "roundTrips": 0,
  "isDayTrader": false,
  "isClosingOnlyRestricted": false,
  "positions": [
    {
      "shortQuantity": 0,
      "averagePrice": 0,
      "currentDayProfitLoss": 0,
      "currentDayProfitLossPercentage": 0,
      "longQuantity": 0,
      "settledLongQuantity": 0,
      "settledShortQuantity": 0,
      "agedQuantity": 0,
      "instrument": "\"The type <Instrument> has the following subclasses [Equity, FixedIncome, MutualFund, CashEquivalent, Option] descriptions are listed below\"",
      "marketValue": 0
    }
  ],
  "orderStrategies": [
    {
      "session": "'NORMAL' or 'AM' or 'PM' or 'SEAMLESS'",
      "duration": "'DAY' or 'GOOD_TILL_CANCEL' or 'FILL_OR_KILL'",
      "orderType": "'MARKET' or 'LIMIT' or 'STOP' or 'STOP_LIMIT' or 'TRAILING_STOP' or 'MARKET_ON_CLOSE' or 'EXERCISE' or 'TRAILING_STOP_LIMIT' or 'NET_DEBIT' or 'NET_CREDIT' or 'NET_ZERO'",
      "cancelTime": {
        "date": "string",
        "shortFormat": false
      },
      "complexOrderStrategyType": "'NONE' or 'COVERED' or 'VERTICAL' or 'BACK_RATIO' or 'CALENDAR' or 'DIAGONAL' or 'STRADDLE' or 'STRANGLE' or 'COLLAR_SYNTHETIC' or 'BUTTERFLY' or 'CONDOR' or 'IRON_CONDOR' or 'VERTICAL_ROLL' or 'COLLAR_WITH_STOCK' or 'DOUBLE_DIAGONAL' or 'UNBALANCED_BUTTERFLY' or 'UNBALANCED_CONDOR' or 'UNBALANCED_IRON_CONDOR' or 'UNBALANCED_VERTICAL_ROLL' or 'CUSTOM'",
      "quantity": 0,
      "filledQuantity": 0,
      "remainingQuantity": 0,
      "requestedDestination": "'INET' or 'ECN_ARCA' or 'CBOE' or 'AMEX' or 'PHLX' or 'ISE' or 'BOX' or 'NYSE' or 'NASDAQ' or 'BATS' or 'C2' or 'AUTO'",
      "destinationLinkName": "string",
      "releaseTime": "string",
      "stopPrice": 0,
      "stopPriceLinkBasis": "'MANUAL' or 'BASE' or 'TRIGGER' or 'LAST' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'ASK_BID' or 'MARK' or 'AVERAGE'",
      "stopPriceLinkType": "'VALUE' or 'PERCENT' or 'TICK'",
      "stopPriceOffset": 0,
      "stopType": "'STANDARD' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'LAST' or 'MARK'",
      "priceLinkBasis": "'MANUAL' or 'BASE' or 'TRIGGER' or 'LAST' or 'BID' or 'ASK' or 'ASK_BID' or 'MARK' or 'AVERAGE'",
      "priceLinkType": "'VALUE' or 'PERCENT' or 'TICK'",
      "price": 0,
      "taxLotMethod": "'FIFO' or 'LIFO' or 'HIGH_COST' or 'LOW_COST' or 'AVERAGE_COST' or 'SPECIFIC_LOT'",
      "orderLegCollection": [
        {
          "orderLegType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
          "legId": 0,
          "instrument": "\"The type <Instrument> has the following subclasses [Equity, FixedIncome, MutualFund, CashEquivalent, Option] descriptions are listed below\"",
          "instruction": "'BUY' or 'SELL' or 'BUY_TO_COVER' or 'SELL_SHORT' or 'BUY_TO_OPEN' or 'BUY_TO_CLOSE' or 'SELL_TO_OPEN' or 'SELL_TO_CLOSE' or 'EXCHANGE'",
          "positionEffect": "'OPENING' or 'CLOSING' or 'AUTOMATIC'",
          "quantity": 0,
          "quantityType": "'ALL_SHARES' or 'DOLLARS' or 'SHARES'"
        }
      ],
      "activationPrice": 0,
      "specialInstruction": "'ALL_OR_NONE' or 'DO_NOT_REDUCE' or 'ALL_OR_NONE_DO_NOT_REDUCE'",
      "orderStrategyType": "'SINGLE' or 'OCO' or 'TRIGGER'",
      "orderId": 0,
      "cancelable": false,
      "editable": false,
      "status": "'AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER' or 'AWAITING_CONDITION' or 'AWAITING_MANUAL_REVIEW' or 'ACCEPTED' or 'AWAITING_UR_OUT' or 'PENDING_ACTIVATION' or 'QUEUED' or 'WORKING' or 'REJECTED' or 'PENDING_CANCEL' or 'CANCELED' or 'PENDING_REPLACE' or 'REPLACED' or 'FILLED' or 'EXPIRED'",
      "enteredTime": "string",
      "closeTime": "string",
      "tag": "string",
      "accountId": 0,
      "orderActivityCollection": [
        "\"The type <OrderActivity> has the following subclasses [Execution] descriptions are listed below\""
      ],
      "replacingOrderCollection": [
        {}
      ],
      "childOrderStrategies": [
        {}
      ],
      "statusDescription": "string"
    }
  ],
  "initialBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "cashAvailableForTrading": 0,
    "cashAvailableForWithdrawal": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "longStockValue": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "shortStockValue": 0,
    "isInCall": false,
    "unsettledCash": 0,
    "cashDebitCallValue": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "accountValue": 0
  },
  "currentBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarketValue": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "savings": 0,
    "shortMarketValue": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "cashAvailableForTrading": 0,
    "cashAvailableForWithdrawal": 0,
    "cashCall": 0,
    "longNonMarginableMarketValue": 0,
    "totalCash": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "cashDebitCallValue": 0,
    "unsettledCash": 0
  },
  "projectedBalances": {
    "accruedInterest": 0,
    "cashBalance": 0,
    "cashReceipts": 0,
    "longOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "liquidationValue": 0,
    "longMarketValue": 0,
    "moneyMarketFund": 0,
    "savings": 0,
    "shortMarketValue": 0,
    "pendingDeposits": 0,
    "cashAvailableForTrading": 0,
    "cashAvailableForWithdrawal": 0,
    "cashCall": 0,
    "longNonMarginableMarketValue": 0,
    "totalCash": 0,
    "shortOptionMarketValue": 0,
    "mutualFundValue": 0,
    "bondValue": 0,
    "cashDebitCallValue": 0,
    "unsettledCash": 0
  }
}

//The class <Instrument> has the 
//following subclasses: 
//-Equity
//-FixedIncome
//-MutualFund
//-CashEquivalent
//-Option
//JSON for each are listed below: 

//Equity:
{
  "assetType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
  "cusip": "string",
  "symbol": "string",
  "description": "string"
}

//OR

//FixedIncome:
{
  "assetType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
  "cusip": "string",
  "symbol": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "maturityDate": "string",
  "variableRate": 0,
  "factor": 0
}

//OR

//MutualFund:
{
  "assetType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
  "cusip": "string",
  "symbol": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "type": "'NOT_APPLICABLE' or 'OPEN_END_NON_TAXABLE' or 'OPEN_END_TAXABLE' or 'NO_LOAD_NON_TAXABLE' or 'NO_LOAD_TAXABLE'"
}

//OR

//CashEquivalent:
{
  "assetType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
  "cusip": "string",
  "symbol": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "type": "'SAVINGS' or 'MONEY_MARKET_FUND'"
}

//OR

//Option:
{
  "assetType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'",
  "cusip": "string",
  "symbol": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "type": "'VANILLA' or 'BINARY' or 'BARRIER'",
  "putCall": "'PUT' or 'CALL'",
  "underlyingSymbol": "string",
  "optionMultiplier": 0,
  "optionDeliverables": [
    {
      "symbol": "string",
      "deliverableUnits": 0,
      "currencyType": "'USD' or 'CAD' or 'EUR' or 'JPY'",
      "assetType": "'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'"
    }
  ]
}

//The class <OrderActivity> has the 
//following subclasses: 
//-Execution
//JSON for each are listed below: 

//Execution:
{
  "activityType": "'EXECUTION' or 'ORDER_ACTION'",
  "executionType": "'FILL'",
  "quantity": 0,
  "orderRemainingQuantity": 0,
  "executionLegs": [
    {
      "legId": 0,
      "quantity": 0,
      "mismarkedQuantity": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "time": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you don't know which of the 5 `Instrument`s you will get until you get the JSON?

Comment: @Sweeper, exactly

Comment: What is the purpose of a Protocol without any property/requirement?

Comment: Hi @LeoDabus, I was hoping  you would help on this.  I am using a protocol so that any of those conforming types can be swapped in for the `instrument` property of the `Position`  struct.  If there is a better way, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I added getters for the common properties, but I don't see it having any bearing on the issue at hand.

Comment: Hmm... I think that would require a few distracting changes in the conforming structs.  I think I'll hold off unless you recommend it.

Comment: How awful would it be replace to protocol and structs with an Instrument superclass and subclasses? Sometimes the old ways are best... and the types do have some commonality I think. The generic then goes away and the birds sing. Of course, you’re now typing the property as the superclass, but is that really so terrible?

Comment: @matt, I'll try that.

Comment: @ScottyBlades it would help also if you post a JSON sample

Comment: @LeoDabus done.

Comment: Post an actual response

Comment: @LeoDabus, okay, one moment.

Comment: @LeoDabus, okay, one moment, it will take some time for me to get that, because I have to get the access token, and to get that I need the refresh token which is in my keychain and to access that I have to make my app compile, which will take some time as I'm in the middle of converting the protocol which wasn't compiling to classes which I'm also having trouble getting to compile.

Comment: @ScottyBlades no problem. Take your time

Comment: Actually let me stash the changes...

Comment: @LeoDabus, done.

Comment: @ScottyBlades I have posted a start point. If you have other JSON that might not get decoded let me know

Comment: If the `assetType` in the 5 `instrument` dictionaries is unique then an enum with associated types might be the most reasonable solution.

Comment: @vadian, that definitely sounds interesting, can you elaborate?

Comment: I just figured out that according to the JSON definition the `assetType` of `Equity` for example can be *"'EQUITY' or 'OPTION' or 'INDEX' or 'MUTUAL_FUND' or 'CASH_EQUIVALENT' or 'FIXED_INCOME' or 'CURRENCY'"* so enum with associated types makes no sense.

Comment: @matt, as I am attempting to convert the values to classes, I'm finding that I have to manually write out all the initializers and the decodable initializer because it isn't provided by default just the same as when I'm using protocols. unfortunately.  It all seems to defeat the "ease of use" purpose of Codable.

Comment: Oh yes, I have implemented that as an enum as follows: `enum AssetType: String, Codable {
    case EQUITY, OPTION, INDEX, MUTUAL_FUND, CASH_EQUIVALENT, FIXED_INCOME, CURRENCY
}` The challenge I have is with the generic Instrument type which can be any of 5 different objects.

Comment: The *"ease of use" purpose of Codable* depends on consistent JSON. This JSON is very complicated and inconsistent (why is the assetType of the instruments not unique?) So you have to write all that annoying boilerplate code. A generic approach cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

```
// MARK: - Root
struct Root: Codable {
    let securitiesAccount: SecuritiesAccount
}

// MARK: - SecuritiesAccount
struct SecuritiesAccount: Codable {
    let type, accountId: String
    let roundTrips: Int
    let isDayTrader, isClosingOnlyRestricted: Bool
    let positions: [Position]
    let initialBalances: InitialBalances
    let currentBalances: [String: Double]
    let projectedBalances: ProjectedBalances
}

// MARK: - InitialBalances
struct InitialBalances: Codable {
    let accruedInterest: Int
    let cashAvailableForTrading, cashAvailableForWithdrawal, cashBalance: Double
    let bondValue, cashReceipts: Int
    let liquidationValue: Double
    let longOptionMarketValue: Int
    let longStockValue: Double
    let moneyMarketFund, mutualFundValue, shortOptionMarketValue, shortStockValue: Int
    let isInCall: Bool
    let unsettledCash, cashDebitCallValue, pendingDeposits: Int
    let accountValue: Double
}

// MARK: - Position
struct Position: Codable {
    let shortQuantity: Int
    let averagePrice, currentDayProfitLoss, currentDayProfitLossPercentage: Double
    let longQuantity, settledLongQuantity, settledShortQuantity: Int
    let instrument: Instrument
    let marketValue: Double
}

// MARK: - Instrument
struct Instrument: Codable {
    let assetType, cusip, symbol: String
}

// MARK: - ProjectedBalances
struct ProjectedBalances: Codable {
    let cashAvailableForTrading, cashAvailableForWithdrawal: Double
}
```

---

```
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(root)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This works in the short term, but I don't think this will work  if I have a cashEquivalent instrument position, FixedIncome instrument position, Equity instrument position, MutualFund instrument position, option position with all details, because those cases won't be covered.

Comment: I need the json sample

Comment: ok, let me add an alternate potentiality.  I am going to rest and then add it tomorrow.